# Connection Limit in Adobe AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air, adobe

I have an Adobe AIR application that makes multiple connections to a server.  When I open more than two connections I get an error:

## 2032: Stream Error.

Is there a configuration option or a property somewhere to raise the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with a configuration for this, but I have a theory you might test.  Flash is single threaded, but handles requests asynchronously.  It still has to handle the input of streams through its one thread.  If you are open connections that stream/stay open for a long time, there is probably some blocking going on that could be longer than the allowed stream buffer blocking tolerance.  Perhaps flash can handle 2 connections, but introducing the third starts to cause a stream to block too long.  This is not exactly a solution, but may get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitation you may check this forum https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1281685
Also you should provide some details like sdk version,os etc

Comment: Please provide specific answers from the linked forum if you are able to, or if not request more information from the poster in a comment. Link-only answers are not considered good practice.